# Line break in expression

Tags: r, expression

Is it possible to produce a line break in the expression() function? The text in bold needs to be broken into at least 2 sentences.

```
plot (DAC~Chlo, data = brazilw, pch = 15, col = "red", cex = 0.5,
  **main=expression("Fig. 3. Relationship between diffuse attenuation coefficient at 490 nm (K"[d]*") and chlorophyll concentration at three coral reef sites")**,
  xlab = expression("Chlorophyll concentration (mg "*m^{-3}*")"),
  cex.lab = 0.8, cex.main = 0.8, cex.axis = 0.8, font.main=1,
  ylim = c(0,0.3), xlim = c(0,3.5), ylab = expression("K"[d]*"(m "*-1^{-1}*")"))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about accepting some of the answers that people have given you already.

Comment: You need `"\n"`. e.g. `"Fig. 3. Relationship between\ndiffuse attenuation"` will introduce a line break between `"between"` and `"diffuse"`

Answer (score 1):

The expression `atop(x, y)` means *'x over y (no horizontal bar)'* (see `?plotmath`).

This means we can use this as a kind of hack:

```r
plot(x = 1, 
     main = expression(paste(atop('Fig. 3. Relationship between', 'case A and B'))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, your code snippet won't run since I don't have your data set, but just insert `\n` into your string wherever you want a newline.

Here's a simple plot with your title:

```
plot(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, main=expression("Fig. 3. Relationship between diffuse attenuation coefficient at 490 nm (K"[d]*") and chlorophyll concentration at three coral reef sites"))
```

Run it in R and your title stretches off the edge of the plot window. Now run it with some newlines added:

```
plot(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, main=expression("Fig. 3. Relationship between\n diffuse attenuation\n coefficient at 490 nm (K"[d]*")\n and chlorophyll concentration at three\n coral reef sites"))
```

The newlines are added, but wont all fit in the top margin, you change the `mai` parameter for that: par(mai = c(1,1,x,0.5)) where x is the size in inches of your top margin. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have attempted to use \n many times and it creates a massive gap mid sentence on the 2nd line of the text. Is their a function that allows a line break on the expression function?